# Is it possible to add a static variable to a C++ struct?

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error when trying to add a static variable to my struct:

> Undefined Symbole s2::aa in module
>   file_name.cpp

`s2` is the name of the structure and `aa` is the static variable.
The compiler I am using is Turbo C++ 3.0.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Please edit your post: the title says "not allowed in structure" but the body says "Is it possible to declare static variables in a Class"

Comment: static variables are allowed in a structure - and I think you need to edit your question

Comment: is this a question.  Statics ARE allowed in a structure.

Comment: @Goz-hehhe..so funny..look at the question, "I said static variables are.... 
instead of statics are....loll

Comment: Such a joy to be able to add the tag turbo-c++3.0 to a question!

Comment: @Earwicker I don't think that it is really a TC++ problem, so perhaps you could restrain yourself. Why do so many people think that tags are a means of self-expression rather than an indexing mechanism?

Comment: True - I assumed it was a TC++ problem at first, then posted a better idea. Have removed the tag.

Comment: It's hard to say if it *is* a TC++ problem though, when we can't see his code. It could certainly be the problem Earwicker pointed out in his answer, but if he does that, and still gets an error, it could be the compiler. What's the problem in adding the tag?

Comment: @jalf - the OP mentions an "undefined symbol" linker error in a comment below, so it's pretty sure to be the lack of a definition. As Neil says, the only reason for using that tag would be as a means of self-expression, but to that end I'd rather perform a conceptual dance, or play the trombone, or maybe both at the same time.

Answer (score 16):

I think you've probably forgotten to define the storage for the static variable:

```
int C::v = 0;
```

Comment: Although, in this case, the "= 0" is optional; IIRC (on some platforms), static data that are at default values can be allocated in .bss, whereas initialized data would be in .data.

Comment: Static data is zero-initted on all platforms. Can be nasty if you change your mind and use the heap instead. Suddenly you discover that you forgot to init a member of the class.

Answer (score 9):

Static variable isn't allowed in structs *in C* because C requires the whole stucture elements to be placed together. To get an element value from a structure you count by the offset of the element from the beginning address of the structure.

However as far as I know you can have a static member in a C++ structure. Are you getting a specific error (which compiler?)

Comment: Yes I have got an error.A Linker Error
"Undefined Symbole s2::aa in module file_name.cpp" (here 's2' is the name of the Structure and 'aa' is the static variable)

Turbo C++ 3.0

Comment: Turbo C++ ?? Man, get a real compiler.

Comment: The error, as noted, is not a compilation error; it's a linking error, and happens because s2::aa is not defined anywhere. See Nick Meyer's answer for an example of how such a variable is defined.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you say this?  Under g++ 4.1.2, this compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
   static int test; // declare (usually in header file)
};

int Test::test = 8; // define (usually in source file)

int
main()
{
   std::cout << Test::test << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Static variables **are** allowed in C++ structs (as you say, they are just classes with a different default access specifier).

Static variables **are not** allowed in C structs, however.

Answer (score 3):

This works...

```
typedef struct _X
{
    static int x; // declare (usually in header file)
} X;

int X::x = 1; // define (usually in source file)

void _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("%d", X::x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

effectively, you'll get a public symbol with the name [?test@Test@@2HA] placed in a separate (globally accessible) segment/section in memory...

```
struct Test
{
   static int test; // declare (usually in header file)
};

int Test::test = 8; // define (usually in source file)

int main()
{
   int x = Test::test++;
   return 0;
}
```

will translate in assembly to:

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27027.1 

    TITLE   C:\WORK\C\Cpp\test.cpp
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB LIBCMT
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  ?test@Test@@2HA                 ; Test::test
_DATA   SEGMENT
?test@Test@@2HA DD 08H                  ; Test::test
_DATA   ENDS
PUBLIC  _main
; Function compile flags: /Odtp
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_x$ = -4                        ; size = 4
_main   PROC
; File c:\work\c\cpp\test.cpp
; Line 9
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx
; Line 10
    mov eax, DWORD PTR ?test@Test@@2HA      ; Test::test
    mov DWORD PTR _x$[ebp], eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR ?test@Test@@2HA      ; Test::test
    add ecx, 1
    mov DWORD PTR ?test@Test@@2HA, ecx      ; Test::test
; Line 11
    xor eax, eax
; Line 12
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

Compile with:

```
cl /c test.cpp /TP /Fatest.asm /link /NODEFAULTLIB /entry:main
```

Answer (score -1):

In C++ structure,you can use static variables same as class.

But you can't use static variables in C stuctures.
Because in c, we can't access static variable with stucture name. In c++ we can access static member variable with class name,like below.

ClassName::staticVariableName

'C' stucture don't provide such facility but c++ stucture does.